# PowerBI Client does not work with Azure AD service principals

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to get data from PowerBI APIs (using Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2 client dlls). Below is my code:

```
private static async Task getEmbedTokens(string accessToken)
        {
            var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(accessToken, "Bearer");
            var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri("https://api.powerbi.com/"), tokenCredentials);
            var reports = await client.Reports.GetReportsInGroupAsync("<groupid here>");
            // Get the first report in the group.
            var report = reports.Value.FirstOrDefault();
            if (report != null)
            {
                var generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "view");
                var tokenResponse = await client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroupAsync("<group id here>", "<report id here>", generateTokenRequestParameters);
                if (tokenResponse != null)
                {
                    // Generate Embed Configuration.
                    var embedConfig = new EmbedConfig()
                    {
                        EmbedToken = tokenResponse,
                        EmbedUrl = report.EmbedUrl,
                        Id = report.Id
                    };
                }

            }
        }
```

Now I use ADAL to generate bearer tokens and I have tried below 2 scenarios:

**Scenario 1: Use UserCredentials (Service account) to generate bearer tokens**

HereI am using service account to generate bearer tokens. The service account has access to the powerbi dashboard.

```
var credential = new UserPasswordCredential("username@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com", "password");
```

**Scenario 2: Use ClientCredentials (Service principal) to get bearer tokens**

Here I am using client id , client secret of a service principal. The service principal has been granted all permissions for Power BI APIs in Azure AD app registration panel.

```
var clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
```

Scenario 1 works fine, but scenario 2 I get unauthorized error. I have tried to check if there is any way to give the principal access to dashboard thru power bi portal, but could not find any.
I prefer to use service principal, but is it possible to use service principal?

Comment: I think you need to click the `Grant Permissions` button as well (top of the permissions blade for your Azure AD app).

Comment: Grant permissions button was clicked after permissions was selected

Comment: Scratch that. It's not gonna work. That user has a Power BI assigned license that's why its access token can be successfully exchanged for a Power BI token. ClientId and ClientSecret carry no user context and will not work.

Comment: Correct @evilSnobu - scenario2 will work only for authorization_code flow where you have an authorization code + clientid/secret for the azure ad app in the case of powerbi.

Answer (score 0):

currently Power BI doesn't support Service principal / app only tokens.